# Load a Java agent JAR located inside the loader

Tags: java, attach-api

I have two separate projects in my IDE for the agent and for the loader that finds a target VM and loads the agent JAR.

- When the agent project is built, the resulting agent JAR artifact is copied into the loader's resources folder.
- When the loader project is built, the loader JAR contains both loader code and the `agent.jar` in it.

The resulting runnable loader structure looks like this:

```
loader.jar
├── META-INF
│   └── MANIFEST.MF
├── me.domain.loader
│   └── Main.class
└── agent.jar
    ├── META-INF
    │   └── MANIFEST.MF
    └── me.domain.agent
        └── Agent.class
```

From the [VirtualMachine#loadAgent(java.lang.String)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/jdk/api/attach/spec/com/sun/tools/attach/VirtualMachine.html#loadAgent(java.lang.String)) specification, I need to provide a path to the JAR containing the agent as the first parameter.

However, when using `Main.class.getResource("/agent.jar").getPath()` I'm getting an `AgentLoadException: Agent JAR not found or no Agent-Class attribute`. What's the correct way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the agent JAR to be loaded must exist on disk. I've solved this issue by copying the embedded JAR resource into a temporary file:

```java
private static String getTemporaryResource(String resourceName) {

    // Read embedded resource from this JAR
    InputStream resourceStream = Main.class.getResourceAsStream(resourceName);
    if (resourceStream == null) {
        throw new Exception("Resource not found in the JAR");
    }

    // Create a temporary file in %TEMP%/resource5513111026806316867.tmp
    File temporaryFile = File.createTempFile("resource", null);
    temporaryFile.deleteOnExit();

    // Copy the resource data into the temporary file
    Files.copy(resourceStream, temporaryFile.toPath(), StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);

    // Return the path to temporary file
    return temporaryFile.getAbsolutePath();
}
```

I'm then using this temporary path to load the agent:

```java
String tempAgentPath = getTemporaryResource("/agent.jar");
VirtualMachine targetVM = VirtualMachine.attach("1337");
targetVM.loadAgent(tempAgentPath);
```

Answer (score 1):

I already had such issue on a maven project.
Anyway you may need to have a manifest file here in META-INF/MANIFEST.MF:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Agent-Class: com.package.AgentLoader.agentNameHere
Permissions: all-permissions
```

You have more details here:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/manifestindex.html
or
[Agent JAR not found or no Agent-Class attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44311624/agent-jar-not-found-or-no-agent-class-attribute)

Comment: Both loader and agent have manifest files. (I've added META-INF folders to my structure representation to show that)